# Adobe Indesign CS6 - Make Text Frame fit text contents automatically

Tags: adobe-indesign

Is it possible to have a text frame auto-expand to fit the text in Indesign CS6?

So when I continue to add text the frame containing it automatically grows in size and doesn't cut the text and show the overflow indicator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For CS5....

You can use the shortcut for Object > Fitting > Fit Frame to Contents Of course you must then type, hit the shortcut, type, hit the shortcut, etc.

You can pay for the In-Tools.com plug in [Autoflow](http://in-tools.com/autoflowpro.html)

Or you can try the free [AutoFit](http://typefi.com/index.php?Itemid=567) plug in from Typefi.com. This is not CS6 ready however. So you'll have to wait for a CS6 version.

However, in **Indesign CS6** select the text frame and choose **Object > Text Frame Options**. Then click the **Auto-Size** tab and adjust the settings.

[image: Text Frame Options]

Comment: Thanks man! Is it possible to set these settings as default for every text frame?

Comment: If you set something and there is no document open, it generally stays that way. So try setting the options without any file open.

Answer (score 0):

I would set up all the frames and then select them all, then choose the setting. One time!!

Comment: Hi Frederik, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!